# Is there a way to return onSnapshot data from a method without using hooks

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am building a react app with a Firestore Database and I am stuck on using onSnapshots.

When I use getDocs, it works well and returns the data from that collection.

```
const getAircraft = async () => {
    const q = query(aircraftCollection, orderBy('series', 'asc'));
    const aircraft = await getDocs(q);

    const aircraftData = aircraft.docs.map((doc) => ({
        id: doc.id,
        ...doc.data()
    }));

    return aircraftData;
}
```

However, when I use onSnapshot, the return gives me null:
The console log shows the data and even pushes to console when I make changes in Firestore.

```
const getAircraftOnSnapshot = () => {
    const q = query(aircraftCollection, orderBy('series', 'asc'));
    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
        const aircraftData = snapshot.docs.map((doc) => ({
            id: doc.id,
            ...doc.data()
        }));
        // console.log(aircraftData);
        return aircraftData;
    });
    
    return () => unsubscribe();
}
```

I have tried

```
return unsubscribe;
```

But still doesnt work.

Please help.

Comment: Why do you want to use snapshot if you don't want to use state? `onSnapshot` is meant to run continuously, not once

Comment: I use the state in the component, and pull the result of the onSnapshot in the component. I want to keep my DatabaseContext File clean

Comment: Have you tried `get()` as this retrieves the contents of a single document based on this [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/get-data#get_a_document)?

Comment: The get() only gets the documents once or when it is refreshed, onSnapshot gets any changes and updates it on my DOM

Comment: You can try using `collectionData` from rxfire. That applies an observable to a collection and updates it automatically.